# How to get the Log / History give a specific file list using SVNKit?

Tags: svn, logging, history, svnkit, filelist

Given a file list for example A.java, B.java, C.java, D.java, I want to get the History / Log of the file that are present in the file list.

For example

```
Revision 0

Added file A.java

Added file B.java
```

---

```
Revision 1

Modified file B.java

Deleted file A.java

Added file C.java
```

---

```
Revision 2

Added file D.java

Modified file B.java

Modified file C.java
```

---

```
Revision 3

Deleted file  C.java
```

etc...

The history should ONLY show the logs (added/ delete/ modified) of the files in the file list.

How can I do this?
It'll would be nice if you will provided some code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

For local files, have a look at `org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient#doLog` or do the log directly against the repository using `org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository#log`. The code snippet can be found at http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_Repository_History.

Comment: I have check the link, but it print out all the repository history, i only want to see the log entry of the files present in the file list. Is there a way to do it?